# Div Before Body Scrolling like Uber Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a website that has a similar scroll effect to the one right below the signup form on https://www.uber.com. How exactly would I go in implementing this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/letalumil/zVzD6/

Comment: That doesn't work because it scrolls to the content below the green div before going through the whole green div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `div` at the begging of the page and just use following css:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
top: 0;
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zVzD6/165/)

Comment: In the uber website it is impossible for me to skip the scrolling of their div, but in this example, if I drag the scrollbar on the side, it doesn't scroll through the content, how do I fix that?

Comment: @beekeeper not sure what do you mean here, although it the preview will be different in sample as there is two scrolls... you can inspect uber website and it will show that they are using the same method.

Comment: yea sorry for the misunderstanding this works just fine. I just used materializes pushpin.